# Conditional statements in line in React.js (jsx)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm got a React application where I'm using JSX and I have a condition that is: if an input is selected (i.e. is true) pass a particular query through to a search engine. I also want to add background styling to the same condition so I came up with the following:

```
<div style={ui.selected.thisInput && {background: "red"} }></div>
```

I also tried:

```
<div style={{ ui.selected.thisInput ? "background:red" }}></div>
```

Both of which throw errors.

Comment: maybe add the error message and what you do not understand about it.
This isn't correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<div {...(condition ? { style: { background: 'red' } } : {})}></div>
```

or

```
<div style={condition ? { background: 'red' } : {}}></div>
```

As the current one in question:

```
<div style={condition && { background: 'red' }}></div> // Wrong
```

will produce the correct style when condition is `true` but will produce wrong style i.e. `style={false}` when `condition` is false.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div style={{ background:condition?"red":"blue"}}>
```

OR

```
<div style={{ background:condition?"red":""}}>
```

[example](https://codepen.io/yoel311/pen/NWbMNoj)

Comment: This would work but what is the problem with the first one?

Comment: @alisasani the first one returns a boolean value (i.e true or false) and thus cannot be a value for `styles` property